# Install nodejs in python slim buster

Tags: python, node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that starts with

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
```

and I want to install `node.js` and `npm` in it. How can I install them in this image?

Comment: Follow the Nodejs Ubuntu/Debian installation documentation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster

# setup dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install xz-utils
RUN apt-get -y install curl

# Download latest nodejs binary
RUN curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.15.4/node-v14.15.4-linux-x64.tar.xz -O

# Extract & install
RUN tar -xf node-v14.15.4-linux-x64.tar.xz
RUN ln -s /node-v14.15.4-linux-x64/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
RUN ln -s /node-v14.15.4-linux-x64/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm
RUN ln -s /node-v14.15.4-linux-x64/bin/npx /usr/local/bin/npx
```

To run node start it with `docker run -it <containerName> /bin/bash`
Then node, npm and npx are available

Answer (score 2):

npm globally packages need to add links if you want to use it as command.

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
ENV NODE_VERSION 14.15.4

#if build in `china`, debian mirrors, npm registry change to china source
ARG AREA=london

RUN set -ex \
    && if [ 'china' = "$AREA" ] ; then \
        sed -i "s@http://deb.debian.org@https://mirrors.aliyun.com@g" /etc/apt/sources.list; \
    fi \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y git xz-utils curl \

    # install node
    && curl "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -O \
    && tar -xf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
    && ln -s "/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/node" /usr/local/bin/node \
    && ln -s "/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/npm" /usr/local/bin/npm \
    && ln -s "/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/npx" /usr/local/bin/npx \

    # npm install bump, openapi-generator
    && if [ 'china' = "$AREA" ] ; then \
        npm config set registry https://registry.npm.taobao.org/; \
    fi \
    && npm install -g bump-cli@2.1.0 \
    && ln -s "/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64/bin/bump" /usr/local/bin/bump \ 

    # clear
    && npm cache clean --force \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -f "/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the official installation for Debian from [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#debinstall) :

```
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | bash - &&\
   apt-get install -y nodejs
```